# Do not escape URL or data URI

Tags: rythm

I have an issue with Rythm improperly escaping some parts of the template.

My use cases are as follows.

```
<img src="data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' viewBox='0 0 512 512'%3E%3Cpath d='M256 8C119.033 8 8 119.033 8 256s111.033 248 248 248 248-111.033 248-248S392.967 8 256 8zm0 48c110.532 0 200 89.451 200 200 0 110.532-89.451 200-200 200-110.532 0-200-89.451-200-200 0-110.532 89.451-200 200-200m140.204 130.267l-22.536-22.718c-4.667-4.705-12.265-4.736-16.97-.068L215.346 303.697l-59.792-60.277c-4.667-4.705-12.265-4.736-16.97-.069l-22.719 22.536c-4.705 4.667-4.736 12.265-.068 16.971l90.781 91.516c4.667 4.705 12.265 4.736 16.97.068l172.589-171.204c4.704-4.668 4.734-12.266.067-16.971z'/%3E%3C/svg%3E">
```

An image tag with properly encoded data URI will be escaped and ruined. Rythm will escape svg+xml

I have tried storing the data URI in a variable and then using

```
<img src="@iconData.raw()">
```

or wraping the image tag in

```
@raw() {
    @myVariable
}
```

The output is always modified by Rythm:

```
<img src="data:image/svg&#43;xml,%3Csvg
```

What else can I do to completely disable escaping and output the content "as is" without ANY modifications? Thanks a lot for any tips :)

Comment: What is the raw content of your `iconData` or `myVariable`? Can you give me a simple example?

Comment: Hi, the dataURI is given in my question - it contains "plus" sign (+) - please see image tag with [src] attribute that contains SVG icon in form of dataURI.

The same goes for URL: https://example.com/display/HHM/HDC+Customers+configuration+-+with+authentication+methods

For data URI, input of [<img src="data:image/svg+xml] will be converted to [<img src="data:image/svg&#43;xml]

Comment: @gelin-luo could I create a Fiddle for you somehow if you want to take a look at it? I don't think I can add anything to "official" Rythm fiddle right?

Comment: Hi sorry for the delay. Here is a fiddle I've created: http://fiddle.rythmengine.org/#/editor/cef9e9e68cb24d9caab61e49983b7eca couldn't reproduce your issue